# MSTest hangs when executing web tests

Tags: mstest, tfsbuild

I'm working on a test migration of a TFS server from 2010 to 2012. We've taken a proof-of-concept server and successfully upgraded it to TFS2012. Now we're trying to repurpose an older build controller, running TFS2010 on Windows 2003 , to run the builds. The builds are a bit on the ancient side; they originally were created for TFS2005 and were upgraded directly to TFS2010 at some point in the past, but still use MSBuild scripts and the Upgrade Template. The vast majority of the codebase is still targeting .NET 2.0 and VS2005, although this will be changing shortly.

So, that's the background. On the TFS2012 build controller, everything builds successfully and the tests run. Hooray! Now onto the problem.

On the TFS1010 build controller, everything builds successfully, but the web tests are "hanging". When executed manually from the command line, it just says "Starting Execution", and then sits there for a couple of hours and eventually times out. There *are* unit tests, and they *do* run, so it's something specifically happening with web tests.

What's interesting is that the TFS2012 build controller is obviously using the 2012 version of MSTest, in the \Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\ folder, and the TFS2010 build controller is using the VS2010 version. When I run the same tests via the command line on the 2012 build controller with the VS2010 version of MSTest, the same issue occurs.

I've confirmed that the TFS2010 build server is running VS2010 Ultimate SP1, with all appropriate updates installed via Windows Update. It was originally running Premium, and the web tests not working actually made sense at that point. I did a complete uninstall of Premium, then installed Ultimate. TFS2010 is patched to SP1 and has CU 2 installed.

The TFS2012 server is running Update 2.

Here's a log from the build server of the issue occurring:

```
  TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://[redacted]:8080/tfs/eCommerce" BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/46594" (TaskId:4359)
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe /nologo /usestderr /testSettings:"G:\Builds\19\124\Sources\Main\Source\ES_[redacted].testrunconfig" /searchpathroot:"G:\Builds\19\124\Binaries\ESIntegration" /resultsfileroot:"G:\Builds\19\124\TestResults" /testmetadata:"G:\Builds\19\124\Sources\Main\Tests\WebTests\Common\SmokeTests\SmokeTests.vsmdi" /testlist:"Division1" /testlist:"Division2" /publish:"http://[redacted]:8080/tfs/ecommerce" /publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/46594" /teamproject:"Web" /platform:"Any CPU" /flavor:"ESIntegration"  (TaskId:4359)
  Loading G:\Builds\19\124\Sources\Main\Source\ES_[redacted].testrunconfig... (TaskId:4359)
  The file 'G:\Builds\19\124\Sources\Main\Source\ES_[redacted].testrunconfig' was created in an earlier version of Visual Studio. This file will be converted, in memory only, to the current format. (TaskId:4359)
  Loading G:\Builds\19\124\Sources\Main\Tests\WebTests\Common\SmokeTests\SmokeTests.vsmdi... (TaskId:4359)
   (TaskId:4359)
  Search path(s) for tests: (TaskId:4359)
  G:\Builds\19\124\Binaries\ESIntegration (TaskId:4359)
  G:\Builds\19\124\Sources\Main\Tests\WebTests\Common\SmokeTests (TaskId:4359)
  Search path(s) for default test settings: (TaskId:4359)
  G:\Builds\19\124\Sources\Main\Tests\WebTests\Common\SmokeTests (TaskId:4359)
   (TaskId:4359)
  Starting execution... (TaskId:4359)
   (TaskId:4359)
  Results               Top Level Tests (TaskId:4359)
  -------               --------------- (TaskId:4359)
  Timeout               (Division1/)SmokeTests.Division1 (TaskId:4359)
  Timeout               (Division2/)SmokeTests.Division2 (TaskId:4359)
  0/2 test(s) Passed, 2 Timeout (TaskId:4359)
```

Note that the tests have the same issue when running from the IDE on the build controller.

Comment: I was about to answer `Install VS 2010 SP1` but you have done it. Is it only hanging on web tests?

Comment: Yes. Unit tests run fine. I'm planning to totally uninstall VS2010 and TFS2010 and reinstall both, although I'm not confident that it will do anything.

Comment: Consider logging a bug - http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: Did you apply the [Compatibility GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082) on the build server?

Comment: @KMoraz Yes. This issue is also happening when running the tests from the IDE, outside the context of a TFS build.

Comment: I've seen some VS addons that cause this. Does running VS in safe mode (`devenv /safemode`) makes any difference?

Comment: @KMoraz It also happens *outside* the context of the IDE, so it's not an add-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a total uninstall of VS2010 and TFS2010, then reinstalled everything in this order:

1. VS2010 Ultimate
2. All VS2010 updates from Windows Update
3. VS2010 SP1 (from Windows Update as well)
4. TFS 2010
5. TFS 2010 SP1
6. TFS 2010 SP1 CU2
7. [TFS 2012 Compatibility GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)

Then I configured the build server and agent. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, I'm experiencing the same issue. When you reinstall VS2010 SP1 then MSTest works for VS2010, but breaks for VS2012. Probably a shared component. It's a bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728659/mstest-not-working-after-installing-vs11-next-to-vs10#

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone, I ran into this problem because I had a "PAUSE" statement in my setup script batch file.